# Error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I know that this question has been asked several times on this platform, however, none of them is able to solve my problem.

I am getting this error from the code below.

```
//This is working
$edition=mysqli_query($con,"select Price from books where Name='$book'");

//This is showing an error. The query is working when I run it on phpmyadmin.
//$edition=mysqli_query($con,"select Price from books where Name='$book' and Edition='$edition'");

//I am using mysqli_fetch_assoc to store it in $row and use the answer for later.
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($edition);
```

Let me know the problem and solution. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What is `$book` set to?

Comment: The form takes book name from user and saves it in $book.

Comment: $book is fine as it works , the value stored is $edition is incorrect, your are expecting string but somewhere in your code it gets charged with an object, just back trace it and find where it changed. other alternative is to debug your code and check its value just before using it to make your query

Comment: Yea, $edition is an Integer.

Comment: Is that the mistake? What should I do than?

Comment: @Ali, I got the mistake. You were right. :) Thanks a ton!

Comment: Can I suggest @Ali post the answer as an answer below so user134179 can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go then :)

Considering in your working example the variable `$book` already been used, my bet would be on the only other variable `$edition`. I was thinking if you could debug the code and check the value assigned to it just before  using it to make your query, you could confirm if it is a acceptable type.